# How to run Odoo tests unittest2?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, python-unittest

I tried running odoo tests using --test-enable, but it won't work. I have a couple of questions.

According to the documentation Tests can only be run during module installation, what happens when we add functionality and then want to run tests?

Is it possible to run tests from IDE like Pycharm ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@aftab You need add `log-level` please see below.

```
./odoo.py -d <dbname> --test-enable --log-level=test
```

and regarding you question, If you are making changes to installed modules and need to re test all test cases then you need to simple restart you server with `-u <module_name>` or `-u all`(for all modules) with the above command.

Comment: Bazzinga, would you know how can we run tests from IDE like Pycharm and also how to mock Odoo models?

Comment: Sorry no idea, using sublime ;)

Comment: and do you know about mocking the models?

Comment: sorry for not being clear, I meant mocking objects https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Comment: It's also good practice to include ` --stop-after-init` if you want to stop odoo after running tests.

Answer (score 5):

This useful For Run odoo test case:

```
./odoo.py -i/-u module_being_tested -d being_used_to_test --test-enable
```

Common options:

```
 -i INIT, --init=INIT
       install one or more modules (comma-separated list, use "all" for all modules), requires -d

-u UPDATE, --update=UPDATE
       update one or more modules (comma-separated list, use "all" for all modules). Requires -d.
```

Database related options:

```
-d DB_NAME, --database=DB_NAME
       specify the database name
```

Testing Configuration:

```
 --test-enable:  Enable YAML and unit tests.
```

Comment: your answer was also helpful, but --log-level=test would show it in a nice format.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a REALLY nice plugin to run unit odoo tests directly with pytest:

https://github.com/camptocamp/pytest-odoo

Here's a result example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run odoo's tests using pycharm, to achieve this I used docker + pytest-odoo + pycharm (using remote interpreters).

First you setup a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM odoo:14
USER root
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        python3-pip
RUN pip3 install pytest-odoo coverage pytest-html
USER odoo
```

And a docker-compose.yml like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    container_name: plusteam-odoo-web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: odoo:14
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo
      - ./config:/etc/odoo
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
    command: --dev all
  db:
    container_name: plusteam-odoo-db
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
      - odoo-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
volumes:
  odoo-web-data:
  odoo-db-data:
```

So we extend an odoo image with packages to generate coverage reports and `pytest-odoo`

Once you have this, you can run `docker-compose up -d` to get your odoo instance running, the odoo container will have `pytest-odoo` installed, the next part is to tell pycharm to use a remote interpreter with the odoo modified image including the `pyest-odoo` package:

[image]

Now every time you run a script in pycharm they will launch a new container based on the image you provided.

After examining the containers launched by pycharm I realized they bind the project's directory to the `/opt/project/` directory inside the container, this is useful because you will need to modify the `odoo.conf` file when you run your tests.
[image]

You can customize the database connection for a custom testing db which you should do, and the important part is that you need to map the `addons_path` option to `/opt/project/addons` or the final path inside the containers launched by pycharm where your custom addons are available.

With this you can create a pycharm script for pytest like this:

[image]

Notice how we provided the path for the odoo config with modifications for testing, this way the odoo available in the container launched by pycharm will know where your custom addon's code is located.

Now we can run the script and even debug it and everything will work as expected.

[image]

I go further in this matter (my particular solution) in a medium article, I even wrote a repository with a working demo so you can try it out, hope this helps:

https://medium.com/plusteam/how-to-run-odoo-tests-with-pycharm-51e4823bdc59 https://github.com/JSilversun/odoo-testing-example

Be aware that using remote interpreters you just need to make sure the odoo binary can find the addons folder properly and you will be all set :) besides using a Dockerfile to extend an image helps to speed up development.