# How can i run a single odoo test file with PyDev unittest in eclipse?

Tags: unit-testing, odoo, pydev

I seted the config data like db_name in setUp()

```
def setUp(self):
  config = tools.config
  config['db_name'] = 'test'
  config['db_user'] = 'admin'
  ...
```

and got a "AttributeError: environments" for "return cls._local.environments" in setUp() super

Answer (score 1):

I must say I haven't really used odoo to know what it needs configured, but apparently there's a pytest plugin for it:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-odoo

So, my suggestion would be to try to use pytest instead of unittest.TestCase along with that plugin (which should take care of making the proper setup) -- the only thing in PyDev in this case is ask it to use the pytest runner (see: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_pyunit.html for details on how to configure that).

Comment: I tried pytest-odoo, and it works! I'm so glad! http://stackoverflow.com/a/41862286/2498426